# Which is greater, the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$ or $\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1, 2\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

which is greater? I know that they are both uncountable, but I can't seem to create a bijection between them, so are they of the same size or is one bigger?

Comment: Every real number can be expressed in binary in at least one way.  Also, every real number can be expressed in base three in at least one way.  

The binary numbers can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the base three numbers, with the possible exception of a countable set.

Answer (score 3):

They are the same size.  There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions to $\{0,1\}$ and $3^{\aleph_0}$ to $\{0,1,2\}$.  Then 
$$2^{\aleph_0} \le 3^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} \le \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\left(\aleph_0^2\right)}=2^{\aleph_0}$$
so these are all the same.  Finding an injection both ways is not so hard.  The identity is an injection one way and taking one element of the function to $\{0,1,2\}$ to two elements of the function to $\{0,1\}$ is an injection the other way.

Comment: Very nice!${}{}{}$